# Articles a, an, the in articles of the computer field

Tags: articles

I am writing an article. The main heading of it is this "Create a demo file on deployer host via GitLab CI"

The problem is that I am not sure which article should I use before the "demo file": "a" demo file or "the" demo file?

The demo file could be any text file. It doesn't matter which name and which content. It is only to confirm that the change in its content has changed or not. So it is not specific. So the 'a' article should be used. But on the other hand, the demo file must be on the certain host in the certain folder so it is being specific somehow so the article should be "the".

I explain used words that are connected to the server and network domain:

Gitlab CI - web service

deployer - a name of the host

host - server from the network point of view

The second question: "Do it by ssh-agent". Ssh-agent is known way of transmitting the encrypting key. I am using it the first time in the article. So ssh-agent or the ssh-agent or an ssh-agent?

Comment: I am not a techie. But in general articles are often omitted from titles. How about: Creating demo files on deployer hosts via Gitlab CI ...or...To create demo file on deployer host via Gitlab CI...? Not sure about ssh-agent.

Comment: What @RonaldSole said. But why are you so concerned about a possible article before ***demo file*** when you don't have one before ***deployer host*** or ***GitLab CI*** ?

Comment: @RonaldSole  your example isn't omitting the article, it's just generalizing it to the plural case. If OP wants to focus on **a** particular file then the article is required even in the title.

Comment: True. But as a general description of the process for a title I think the plural serves the purpose by avoiding the issue, whether or not a single file is concerned.

Comment: The fact this is technical is actually irrelevant.

Comment: @RonaldSole The goal is to create just one file not several ones. One is completely enough to confirm that the creating works.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are right as (the) deployer host is considered but I think one must treat GitLab CI as Windows or MS Office. This a name of a tool. Anyway we can talk about the name of the specific CI (Continous Integration too). Maybe even better.

Comment: @Andrew Think about the plurality of the file as about the stone that one needs to test if there is a glass in a frame or not. One stone is enough to throw it and process the test. And it doesn't matter what kind of the stone.

Comment: @trzczy  It would be fine to use the plural, if you're talking about a general case where someone might want to create one or more files, **Creating Demo Files on a Deployer Host in GitLab Cl Using SSH-Agent**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *definite article* "the" is used to describe either something you've mentioned before, or something which is already known to the reader.  However, since you are talking about the title, then this is the first mention of this kind of file.  Also, as you explain, there is nothing special or unique about the demo file that the reader would recognize.  So the *indefinite article* "a" is more appropriate.

> Creating **a** Demo File on a Deployer Host.

(Note I use the gerund *creating* not the verb *create*.  For articles, it's more idiomatic to phrase titles as descriptions of what you explain how to do.  For instruction manuals, it's more idiomatic to phrase titles as actions which the user can perform)

An example of using the definite article in a title:

> Using **the** Euclidean Shortest Path Problem to Define Routes for Self-Driving Vehicles

Not all algorithms will take the definite article though, particularly if there are many possible implementations.  For example, I would likely talk about *a* bubble sort algorithm if it's my own implementation in a specific language, but *the* bubble sort algorithm when talking about it in general.

Similar answer for "ssh-agent".  Since it's a common technique, with nothing special about your implementation, there is no reason to use the definite article.

> Posting a file to a secure server using **an** ssh-agent.

That being said, it could be interpreted as the name of some particular software, in which case you don't need any article:

> Posting a file to a secure server using **SSH-Agent**.